# Does History.back() work in a GWTTestCase?

Tags: gwt, gwttestcase

Does History.back() work in a GWTTestCase?

I have tried verifying the current token immediately after History.back() call and also after a delay using a Timer but it doesn't seem to change. The onValueChange() method doesn't seem to be called either.

I did a Google search for the issue and found a few posts that suggest others have experienced a similar problem but some are dated 2010. I did find one post where Thomas Broyer responded to one person that he observed the same but I am unable to find that post again.

Has anyone had success in testing code involving History.back() from GWTTestCase? If so, I am most likely doing something wrong. If it is a known issue or intended behavior I would appreciate knowing that so that I don't spend any more time on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by [GWT's own tests](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/9472e36/user/test/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HistoryTest.java), it should work, but maybe has quirks.

Comment: They use @DoNotRunWith(Platform.HtmlUnitUnknown) for the method testHistory() that is testing History.back(). From Platform docs I see "HtmlUnitUnknown" defined as "Gwt tests whose failures have not been investigated yet". Does this mean Google GWT team itself knows there is a failure but hasn't investigated it yet? I assume this annotation simply marks the test as successful without actually executing it.

Comment: Ah, good catch. The annotation marks the test as successful (Junit 3 didn't have ignored tests) when run in HtmlUnit, but you can run tests in real browsers too.